# Javascript имитация клика по iframe

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
document.write('<iframe onclick="alert(555)" src="http://hashcode.ru"></iframe>'); // вывод фрейма

function test(){
         alert(window.frames[0].src); // не работает
         window.frames[0].click(); // не работает

}
</script>
```

Как решить проблему?
изменять фрейм нельзя(то есть приписывать name/id/class тд)

Comment: никак, если src не контролируется вами.

Answer (score 1):

window.frames[0] — указывает на window, а не на тег, чтобы получить src надо делать так:

```
document.write('<iframe id="myFrame" onclick="alert(555)" src="http://hashcode.ru"></iframe>');

function test() {
    var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    console.log(frames[0].src);

    // или
    console.log(myFrame.src); // по id фрейма
}
```